# TOC over multiple pages. Only first page is numbered

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

my table of contents is multiple pages long. Only the first page of the toc is numbered, the following pages are not.

You can find my document modified as a MWE below. The first page of the toc is numbered with "iii", where as the the second page of the toc is without a page number.

Can this be fixed?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\title{Test}
\author{Its Me} 
\date{\today{}, Wherever} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{makecell}  
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{sectsty}  
\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyhead[RO RE]{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont \rightmark}  \selectfont
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[RO,RE]{\thepage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, natbib=true, hyperref=true, sorting=none]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\geometry{top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=30mm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font={small},labelfont={bf},labelsep=space,width=.75\textwidth]{caption}
\linespread{1.25} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\chapter*{Abstract}



\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction2}
\chapter{Introduction2}
\chapter{Introduction3}
\chapter{Introduction4}
\chapter{Introduction5}
\chapter{Introduction6}
\chapter{Introduction7}
\chapter{Introduction8}
\chapter{Introduction9}
\chapter{Introduction10}
\chapter{Introduction11}
\chapter{Introduction12}
\chapter{Introduction13}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have `\pagestyle{empty}` so no page numbers by default, except chapter opening pages typically have `\thispagestyle{plain}` so they get a number.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. I've added \pagestyle{plain} before \tableofcontents and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have `\pagestyle{empty}` so no page numbers by default, except chapter opening pages typically have `\thispagestyle{plain}` so they get a number.